# Teamcity 9x Error: Can't find the valid AspnetMergePath

Tags: svn, msbuild, teamcity, teamcity-9.1

I have tried to configure a .net project on teamcity (version -9.1.3 (build 37176)) with MSBuild but getting some error - [Error] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets(132, 5): Can't find the valid AspnetMergePath.

Could someone explain why this error is coming?

Comment: What have you done to try solving the matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Can't find the valid AspnetMergePath" on Visual Web Developer Publish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713714/cant-find-the-valid-aspnetmergepath-on-visual-web-developer-publish)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713714/cant-find-the-valid-aspnetmergepath-on-visual-web-developer-publish/16018389)