# TFS 2013 Isn't Generating Web Deploy Package

Tags: tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

I've found countless threads and blogs telling me how easy this should be but I can't get it working for some reason. When I publish my application through Visual Studio 2013 it builds and creates the .zip file fine. When I build it through TFS2013.2 the application builds but there is not a .zip file.

I'm using the default build definition (Tfvc.Template.12.xaml) and I'm passing in the MSBuild arguments /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true. I also tried with /p:PublishProfile=profileName but it didn't help.

There are no errors in the build log. I added /v:d and nothing came up regarding creating the package. What am I missing or where should I look?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6423232/4905310

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MSBuild log generated by your TFS Build, you should be able to see in there what it's doing when it gets to the Publish step.