# MvcBuildViews true causes "'/temp' is not a valid IIS application" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

After setting `MvcBuildViews` to `true` in my `.csproj` file in order to have the views compile during build, I get the following error:

> '/temp' is not a valid IIS application

I presume that the '/temp' that this is referring to is the path where the views will be compiled. Here's the relevant section in the `.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

I use full IIS to serve up this MVC 5 website on my local machine (haven't tried this on a remote server yet). Do I need to set something up in IIS to make `MvcBuildViews` work correctly?

Comment: I'm having this same problem too, so I've started a bounty.

Comment: Adding `<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>..\bin</BaseIntermediateOutputPa‌​th>` after `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>` element works in most occurences, often apply when another `web.config` file has been present in `obj` directory.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto That didn't help.

Comment: I have a similar issue. But I notice if I manually pass -p to the aspnet_compiler.exe like below, it'll work. However, I don't know how to tell the project file to do that. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v temp -p path-to-output

Answer (score 3):

This is an obscure and head-scratching problem.  As pointed out by John Rutherford above, it shouldn't be necessary and isn't practical to create a "temp" web app on all the build servers.  This is a compile-time issue, not a run-time issue, so IIS shouldn't even be involved.

Here's the answer; there's a fair amount to it.  Credit to the many other people who have also researched this in various ways.

I am using everything up to date as of July, 2021: visual studio 2019, new build server 2019 with latest build tools and updates from visual studio 2019 installer.

1. The offending line in the .csproj is

```
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
```

If you read the spec for the AspNetCompiler clause, you'll see that VirtualPath, while required, is only used if PhysicalPath isn't present.  In fact, I verified that PhysicalPath wasn't present using this directive inside the MvcBuildViews target:

```
<Message Text="WebProjectOutputDir=$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
```

and sure enough, WebProjectOutputDir was blank.  That's the genesis of the misleading "/temp is not a valid IIS application" or "Failed to map the path /temp" error messages from ASPNETCOMPILER.

2. The problem is that your build server doesn't have the right build targets to create a web deploy package.  You can see this if you look at the output - you'll see it stop right after the build, with no output (or error message) for the web deploy package task.  This has been described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409549/web-deploy-packaging-not-working-on-my-build-server

and here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607428/msbuild-target-package-not-found/6413635#6413635

Against all reason, the *only* solution I found that worked consistently was to copy

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications
```

to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0
```

on the build server (yes, I'm using MSBuild 16, go figure).

It has also been suggested that adding the nuget package

```
MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets
```

solves the problem.  It does, but it's a pretty rough thing to have to do to every web project in a large system.

You shouldn't have to do this, of course, but at least you, the build server administrator, can fix it for everyone. I can't see this as anything other than a bug, or at best a miscommunication.

Comment: I had to do this on my developing machine. The two needed folders I obtained from ``C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\``

Comment: Unfortunately, it worked only once. The second compile run ended with the same error again.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1114968.aspx?not+a+valid+IIS+application), I guess you've to make IIS virtual directory names `temp` to point to this application.

Comment: While that probably would solve the issue, I don't think it should be necessary. Nor is it practical to require all of our developers to set this up and to set it up on our build servers.