# MSBuild WebFileSystemPublish step does not run on build server

Tags: .net, powershell, msbuild

I'm using the following powershell script to build a web project:

```
$tools = @()
$tools += "C:\Windows\System32"                           #xcopy
$tools += "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" #msbuild
$env:Path =  [string]::join('; ', $tools)

msbuild ROS.EDI.Web/ROS.EDI.Web.csproj `
  /p:DeployOnBuild=true `
  /p:PublishProfile=$config `
  /p:Configuration=$config `
  /p:Platform=AnyCPU `
  /p:DefineConstants=$constants `
  /property:ApplicationVersion=$env:BUILD_NUMBER `
  /property:ApplicationRevision=$env:BUILD_VCS_NUMBER
```

The script completes and msbuild runs without error on both my dev machine
and the build server. However, the step that publishes the web project to
the local file system does not run on the build server.

Here is the relevant output from msbuild on my dev machine

```
PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder:          
  Publish Pipeline Deploy phase Stage ...
WebFileSystemPublish:                              
  ...
```

And on the build server

```
PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder:             
  Publish Pipeline Deploy phase Stage ...
Package:                                              
  Invoking Web Deploy to generate the package with ...
```

I'm trying to figure out why the "Package" step is running on the build
server instead of "WebFileSystemPublish". What can cause the same version of
msbuild to behave differently on two different machines?

Before you mark this as a duplicate I have read the following and tried
their solutions to no avail:

- [TFS build - deployment/package target does not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045850/tfs-build-deployment-package-target-does-not-run)
- [Web Deploy packaging not working on my build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409549/web-deploy-packaging-not-working-on-my-build-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following msbuild option:

```
/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 `
```

I found out about this option [here](http://sedodream.com/2013/01/06/CommandLineWebProjectPublishing.aspx).